# Filling a certain number of rows in Excel automatically

Tags: excel, rows, fill

How can I fill a certain number of rows in Excel?

Let's say 5 and it fills **5** rows with numbers, like `1 2 3 4 5` (downwards 1 number each cell). If I change it to **12** it should result in `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12`.

I could do it by dragging the formula `=A1+1` down, but then I have to adjust the last number manually (it will vary from ~50 to ~900).

Comment: Do you want/plan to use a programming language? Your question doesn't specify one and doesn't indicate that you're a programmer. I don't think there is a way to do this without using at least some programming

Comment: I have seen the "Series" answer, but I need some sort of automatism: If there is standard excel function/trick would be reeeally nice, otherwise something with VBA/macro as it is built-in. Should then run out-of-the-box on other pcs =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the need for automation is not so great then you can use built-in Excel functionality as outlined in my answer.  If you need a more automated solution then you will have to record a Macro to accomplish it.

Using the `Fill` option from the ribbon/toolbar, select `Series` and then adjust your parameters accordingly, filling in a Column from 1 to n.  Screeshots below:

[image]

This brings up a dialog box which you complete as per your requirements.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok. This solution will require you to paste a formula down your entire possible range (ex. in your case to row 900). Assuming:
- Your first value is in A1
- Your step size is 1
- The number of rows you want to change is in D1,

You should be able to copy the following formula into A2 and then drag it through your desired range:

`=IF(ROW()<=$D$1,A1+1,"")`

The only caveats are: 
- That you can't enter values manually into Column A in that entire range
- There are 900 formulas hanging out and recalculating on your sheet

Comment: thank you! i have seen both proposed solutions can work for me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Click in any cell (let's assume cell `C5`). Type `=ROW()-ROW(C$5)+1` and press enter then drag down the arrow at the bottom right corner to create numbering as far as you want. One nice advantage is that it will not break if you add rows before or within, or delete rows before or within. At any time you can  go to the last cell and drag more to create more numbers and it will pick up right from the last number.